# Purpose of repeat function

Tags: kotlin

Using kotlin I can repeat an action in at least two ways:

```
val times = 5

// First option
for (i in 0 until times) {
    print("Action $i")
}

// Second option
repeat(times) {
    print("Action $it")
}
```

I'd like to know the purpose of [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html).

- Should the traditional `for` loop be replaced with `repeat` function if possible?
- Or are there special cases for this function?
- Are there any advantages in `repeat` function?

---

**EDIT**

I've made some research about this question. As long as kotlin is open source project, I could download the sources and check git history.

I found that

1) `repeat` function is a replace for `times` function extension.

```
public inline fun Int.times(body : () -> Unit)
```

2) [KT-7074](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7074). `times` function has become deprecated. But why?

Comment: The equivalent of `repeat(times)` is `for (i in 0 until times)` and not `for (i in 0..times)`

Comment: It's really just more concise. I don't use it often, but have quite a few times when parsing files. Say a field I parse tells me how many points/position follow, I can use `repeat(numPoints) { points += parsePosition(stream) }` to parse them all. I could have used a `for` but the `repeat` was shorter and I thought it read better.

Comment: Funny thing: `readCount times { rl.unlock() }` - this is the usage of times extension in 2015. No dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of convenience (shortens the code). There are even more ways for example using an `IntRange` and `forEach`

```
(0..4).forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

> 0 1 2 3 4

They all serve the same purpose, so the choice is yours.

You don't need to worry about performance either, since `repeat` and `forEach` are inline functions, which means the lambda code is copied over to the call site at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Next lines are all just my opinion:

- there are no special cases when you should or shouldn't use `repeat`
  function.
- it has more concise syntax.
- In places where you don't need to manipulate the **loop counter** or need to **repeat** only some simple action I would use that function.

It's all up to you to decide when and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From Standard.kt:

```
/**
 * Executes the given function [action] specified number of [times].
 *
 * A zero-based index of current iteration is passed as a parameter to [action].
 *
 * @sample samples.misc.ControlFlow.repeat
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun repeat(times: Int, action: (Int) -> Unit) {
    contract { callsInPlace(action) }

    for (index in 0 until times) {
        action(index)
    }
}
```

As you can see `repeat(times)` is actually `for (index in 0 until times)`.
There is also a zero-based *loop counter* and it is: `it`.

> Should the traditional for loop be replaced with repeat function if
>   possible?

I can't find any reason for that

> Or are there special cases for this function?

None I can think of.

> Are there any advantages in repeat function?

None I can think of, or maybe(?) just 1: 
for educational purposes, I suppose it's easier to teach 
that `repeat(n) { }` *performs n iterations of the block of statements inside the curly brackets*.